# Reverse Percentage to unknown Total value

Tags: excel-formula

I am after the logic to solve this problem.

I know the percentage and the value that the percentage represents ie:

Percentage Value = 12%
$$ Value = 276

What is the total value of the 100%.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards

Shandra

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to remember this is ratios.  12:100 = 276:X

In other words (276 * 100)/12 = X

Answer (score 1):

```
Full * Percentage = Value
Full = Value / Percentage
     = 276 / 0.12
     = 2300
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late answer, you can find my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54125117/850840

At least if others comes here they will find the answer.