# Excel formula for reverse percentage calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a calculation which I am unable to crack.

Lets say my Cost Price is 300. I want to sell the item at No Profit or No Loss. My total commission/expenses will be 30%. So it means i need to sell the item at 390.
But if I do 390 - 30% = 273.

How can I see the item, so that if I minus 30% to it. My Revenue will still be 300.

Comment: There is a flaw in your question.  You stated that commission expenses will be 30% and that the cost price is 300, therefore assumed that your commission will be $90, hence why you did $300 + $90.  Yet, you proceeded to assume that 30% should be taken off from $390.  So now, you need to clarify, whether the commission will be taken off from $300 or $390, the purchase price vs the list price.  You are leaving that undecided at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the formula you want is

```
=300/0.7
```

or

```
=300/(1-30%)
```

basically it is `300= x*(1-.30)` where the `(1-.30)` is the amount that wants to be kept after the commision of 30%.  Solving for x we get the above formula.

Comment: can you please explain once.

Comment: @Lisa, you did misunderstand the question. But you did what most would have done. But in the end would have had loss on that product.

Comment: @Lisa no it is (1-.30) * x = 300.  The cost is 300 and to ensure that the sales rep gets a 30% commision on the sales price it must be `428.5714286`
`

Answer (score 1):

You want Sell Price - 30% Sell Price = Cost Price.

Combining the left two, you have 70% Sell Price = Cost Price.

Divide both sides by 70% and you get Sell Price = (1/0.7) Cost Price.

The fraction 1/0.7 is approximately 1.42857.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, of course. It's the same answer explained differently for OP.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar equation/formula, but then I built it in Excel.

So if you have, say, an item with

```
CostPrice = 200
```

Then you add a `ProfitMargin = 20%` so the

```
SellPrice = 200 + 20% = 240
```

Then the reverse equation for this will be

```
CostPrice = ( SellingPrice * 100 ) / ( ProfitMargin + 100 )

// In your case it should be
CostPrice = ( 240 * 100 ) / ( 20 + 100 )
          = 200
```

Or Simply do the following:

```
CostPrice = SellingPrice / 1.2 = 240 / 1.2 = 200 <-- This will reduce the added 20%
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. None of the people here seemed to understand exactly what you were going for.
Here is the formula I used to get 300 as the answer.

=390/(1+30%)